# MIDI files step by step

Tags: midi

I'd like to code program that will be creating .mid files but I don't really know how to do this. I've read several pages about it but I still don't know how to deal with this. I can't find any examples as well and if I try to read .mid file in notepad I can see some strange characters (i mean NULL etc xd). Is there somebady that could explain me how to do this step by step? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply read it in notepad ! You need to decode it.

This is one library that can help you do that: http://midifile.sapp.org/

This is the standard explanation: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/midi/